# Dual boot with 256GB SSD & 1TB SSD

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot

I have bought a laptop second hand, that has Windows 11 on it. Windows 11 is installed on a 256GB SSD, and the laptop also have a second drive of 1TB that seems to be empty (It says "New Volume (F:)"). I want to dual boot Windows 11 and Ubuntu. How should I configure the dual boot?

I want 500GB windows and 750GB Ubuntu. What would be the best way of achieving this?

Comment: insert the UBuntu installation USB thumb drive and do exactly what you described, i.e. take 750 GB of you 1TB drive and use it for ubuntu? That might sound complicated to you, but it's actually something you can do in the installer quite straightforwardly.

Comment: Dual Boot advice:

I suggest you read `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI` . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: How much are you going to use Windows or Ubuntu. I might shrink Windows by 50GB using WIndows tools and install /(root) to SSD. You then can have /home formatted ext4 on HDD. You can then have rest of HDD as NTFS which can be used for data by both Ubuntu & Windows if Windows fast start up & bitlocker are off, so Linux NTFS driver can use the NTFS.

Comment: @oldfred OP says both are SSDs.

Comment: If both are SSD, then it does not matter where Ubuntu is installed. Then also better to gpt partition in advance & include an ESP for Ubuntu on second drive. And see this bug for any install to second or external drive. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Oldfred uses work around in post#55, but this is probably easier. https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator